# Mouse movement doesn't effect same bone movement. Why?

Tags: bones

If I add a bone constraint (e.g. Limit Rotation...) and move the bone in pose mode I have to move my mouse far until it gets to a zone where the mouse movement effects the bone, so that the bone moves. If I remove the bone constraint everything works fine. What can I do to fix that?

Comment: It sounds like you need to adjust the Min/Max values of your limit - or adjust your Influence slider. I was able to reproduce what you described by leaving an axis' Min and Max values both at 0° and having an Influence somewhere between 0 and 1. Could you tell us more about your settings?

Comment: I figured out, that after I clear transform the bone movement is correct, but if I try to move that bone once again after setting it to a new position, the same issue occurs and I have to clear transform again.